# Have you ever seen this weird IE JavaScript behaviour/bug?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

OK, this is driving me crazy:

First example, no problem:

```
<script>

window.myvar = 150;

if (false) {
  var myvar = 3;
}

// This will popup "150"
alert(myvar)

</script>
```

Now, with TWO script elements:

```
<script>

window.myvar = 150;

</script>

<script>

if (false) {
  var myvar = 3;
}

// This will popup "undefined"
alert(myvar)

</script>
```

Tested with IE8.

Have you any idea why?

Comment: Can you please test if the code at http://tinypaste.com/49c80 shows the same error as above, so I can answer your question? I can't test because I'm not using my Windows box at the moment. Ad@m

Comment: I wish I had IE8 to test right now. Sounds like `myvar`'s definition is being hoisted and shadowing the property of `window`.

Comment: @adam that code tests OK in IE7/8, it alerts 100

Comment: adam, nope. That does not exploit the bug/feature.

Comment: I see... So it must be something to do with the `if(false){}` block, because I didn't add it in the code above. Ad@m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the second example, in your second `script` block, `myvar` has been [hoisted](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) (as per the spec) to the top of the containing scope. Remember JavaScript does not have block scope, only function scope.

Therefore, `var myvar` (the hoisted definition that is interpreted) is going to lead to `myvar` being `undefined` when the `alert()` looks up `myvar` on the [VariableObject](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/variables-vs-properties-in-javascript/#more-1092).

Comment: @sushil I added a link that helpfully explains hoisting in more detail.

Comment: thank you, now it's clear. Don't know why it works differently on other browser though

Comment: @alex I see no hoisting. It is an IE8 bug. IE8 seems to compile script blocks separately. Thus, `myvar` is initialized twice (buggy).  Because `myvar` is initialized in the first block and `if (false)` is unreachable code (not compiled) but it alerts `myvar` as `undefined`. See, no hoisting! "hoisting" defined in the [article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) talks about function scope and global scope.

Answer (score 3):

That's because since javascript does scope based on function levels, your code computes/compiles/equivalent to the following:

```
<script>

window.myvar = 150;

</script>

<script>
var myvar;

if (false) {
  myvar = 3;
}

// This will popup "undefined"
alert(myvar)

</script>
```

Comment: OK, so this has something to do with variable hoisting. Seems only on IE, though.

Comment: jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/upexat/6/edit#source  and another version   http://jsbin.com/upexat/8/edit#source

Answer (score 2):

There's a bit more too it than Alex said (even though he just referenced my article - thanks!).

If the code sequence was in the sequence it appears, "var myVar" would not get hoisted (or rather its hoisting would have no effect) because "window.myvar = 150" is 
defined first (moreover this wouldn't explain why the first example worked and the second one only failed in IE)

It looks like the second script is (somehow) loading before the first one - but only in IE8. 
You can simulate switching the tag sequence and you will see undefined alert in all browsers

```
var myvar;

if (false) {
  myvar = 3;
}

alert(myvar)

window.myvar = 150;
```

Comment: There is no "hoisting"! This is just an IE8 bug. Well written [article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) by the way (for those coming from C family languages)!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't happen to me in iOS Safari on 4.3.1, so it might be a bug in IE. However, @alex's answer may also be true as well. 
Ad@m

Answer (score 0):

I am for hoisting, as alex said. The compiler sees that you define `myvar` in your block (`var myvar` inside `if`) and hoists the previously known `myvar`. I am not sure, whether it is bug or feature, though.